# Error en Cargar PDF Jasper Reports y Netbeans Mysql

Tags: netbeans, jsp, jasper-reports

Estoy teniendo problemas al cargar mi reporte generado por Jasper Report Studios en Netbeans JSP.
Este es mi codigo en mi JSP.

```
 <%
   Connection cn;
   conexion con = new conexion();
   cn = con.getConectar();
    try {
        String jrxmlFile = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("Reportes/rptReporteFinal.jrxml");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,cn);

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
     if(con != null){
     con.cerrarConexion();
     }
     }

   %>
```

y al ejecutar me sale este mensaje.
[image: Error]

Por favor solicito de su gentil ayuda.
Netbeans 8.0.2
Jasper Report Studios 6.10.0
el archivo .Jar la version 6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer es porque no estas pasando los bytes del archivo.pdf hacia el flujo del servlet. Yo tengo esto:

```
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();       
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexion=null;
        conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mybd","user","pass");

        HashMap<String, Object> parameters= new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("cherry.jpg",request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/image/cherry.jpg"));//InputStream imageStream =

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/reportes/ReporteCursoJasper.jrxml"));
        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport,parameters,conexion);          
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    }catch(JRException|ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        // display stack trace in the browser
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
    }
```

Básicamente te faltan estas lineas:

```
bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport,parameters,conexion);          
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

**Actualización:**

Creo que te faltan jars, yo tengo estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estimado eh modificado agregando la linea de los bytes,pero me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje hasta,eh probado con tu codigo pero me marca un error en esta linea =  bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jrxmlFile,null,conexion);

Comment: tal vez sea por la version del PDF o del netbeans,con que version estas trabajando

Comment: Yo creo que te faltan jars.

Comment: un favor puedes pasarme todas esas ..JAR

Comment: No se como, me los pasaron en un usb. Y no tengo ninguna cuenta de almacenamiento en la nube.

Comment: Creo que los bajaron de aqui: https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases

Comment: Gracias estimado